# Conky opens several instances

Tags: linux, fedora, conky

I've been using *conky* for a couple of months already in several of my machines and I've noticed that in almost all of them it runs a bunch of instances, literally seeing the conky process all over the task manager. This either affects the way conky looks or the way my computer runs other programs. I wouldn't like to stop using it, but I think that I'll have to do that in case it is a problem that cannot be solved.

So please, if there's a way to make conky stop doing this, or to tell the system to globally refrain from duplicating processes, I'll be thankful with you.

**Regards**.

PD. For your info, I use a Fedora 19 XFCE Desktop.

Comment: How is conky started?

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин How? Well, it is a startup program if that's what you mean.

Comment: The error lies in how the process is started. Describe *that* as thoroughly as you can. Chances are you'll understand and solve the problem while doing so.

Answer (score 0):

```
pstree -a

  |-conky -d
  |   `-3*[{conky}]
```

That's three threads.

```
   Some objects may create threads, and sometimes these threads will not be destroyed  until  Conky
   terminates.  There is no way to destroy or clean up threads while Conky is running. For example,
   if you use an MPD variable, the MPD thread will keep running until Conky dies. Some threaded ob-
   jects will use one of the parameters as a 'key', so that you only have 1 relevant thread running
   (for example, the $curl, $rss and $weather objects launch one thread per URI).
```

you can use:

> *running_processes*
>   *running_threads*

on Linux - check the *man* page.